# Deploy Laravel on Cloud Foundry

Tags: laravel-5, cloud-foundry

I`m trying to deploy Laravel on Cloud Foundry, but at the end, it failed.
I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/06/17/getting-started-laravel-bluemix/) step by step. Also, I tried to solve my problem by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097591/deploy-a-laravel-app-on-cloudfoundry) but it doesn't work for me. And the overall view of  my app is looks like [this](https://github.com/csterwa/cf-laravel-example)
However this is the errors, when I push the app to cf:

```
WARNING: A version of PHP has been specified in both `composer.json` and `./bp-config/options.json`.
WARNING: The version defined in `composer.json` will be used.
The extension 'fpm' is not provided by this buildpack.
The extension 'tokenizer' is not provided by this buildpack.
  [ErrorException]                                                                                                    
  file_put_contents(/tmp/app/htdocs/bootstrap/cache/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  
-----> Composer command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/scripts/compile.py", line 50, in <module>
    .from_build_pack('lib/additional_commands')
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 208, in extensions
    process_extension(path, ctx, 'compile', process, args=[self])
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 69, in process_extension
    success(getattr(extn, to_call)(*args))
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 414, in compile
    return composer.compile(install)
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/lib/extension_helpers.py", line 154, in compile
    self._compile(install)
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 181, in _compile
    self.run()
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 316, in run
    *self._ctx['COMPOSER_INSTALL_OPTIONS'])
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 360, in run
    shell=True)
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/ca44b1cd9a98d10d3246e577384a9145/lib/build_pack_utils/runner.py", line 109, in stream_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
build_pack_utils.runner.CalledProcessError: Command '<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w' at 0x7fa7340816f0>' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed to compile droplet
Exit status 223
Staging failed: Exited with status 223
```

I need your help to solve this issue!

Comment: Hi, you might have a bit more luck if you open a GitHub issue against the PHP buildpack repository: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack